# Which class template definition does the `extern` instantiations choose in multi-file compilation?

Tags: c++, templates, extern

I have just tried to test how the compiler behaves with template in multi files. In each .cpp file, I defined a class template with the same name but a bit different implementation. See the files below:

- test.h

```cpp
#include <iostream>

//#define FROM_MAIN_CPP     //for choosing main() from which .cpp file
```

- NOT_main.cpp

```cpp
#include "test.h"

//template definition
template <typename T> class cls {
public:
    T prop;
    cls(T _val) : prop(_val) {
        std::cout << "from NOT_main.cpp\n";
    }
};

//template instantiation
template class cls<int>;    
extern template class cls<float>;   //expect definition in main

//testing...
#ifndef FROM_MAIN_CPP
int main(void) {
    cls<int> int_obj(19);
    cls<float> float_obj(1.9f);     //expect definition in main
}
#endif
```

- main.cpp

```cpp
#include "test.h"

//template definition
template <typename T> class cls {
public:
    T prop;
    cls(T _val) : prop(_val) {
        std::cout << "from main.cpp\n";
    }
};

//template instantiation
extern template class cls<int>;     //expect definition in NOT_main
template class cls<float>;

//testing...
#ifdef FROM_MAIN_CPP
int main(void) {
    cls<int> int_obj(19);     //expect definition in NOT_main
    cls<float> float_obj(1.9f);
}
#endif
```

Now I try to compile with the main() functions in each .cpp file. See my test here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AmSZCSVZhJwNP8AxJ0saYeLZANWeX6v2?usp=sharing

I know the `extern` keyword helps the compiler prevent multi instantiations in translation units. I expected when I explicitly instantiated the template defined in first file, then used the declaration with `extern` in other ones, so the template definition used should be the definition in the first.

In detail, with the main() in NOT_main.cpp, it behaved as I expected. But with the main() in main.cpp, why did the compiler choose template defined in main.cpp despite using `extern`.

It would be appreciated if you could point out what's wrong in my understanding.
Thanks and regards.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/1553090)

Comment: This is ODR violation. Program is simply malformed and there are no guarantees.

Comment: The different implementations are required to be identical. Otherwise, the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: @Eljay "different implementation are required to be identical" that's an oxymoron.

Comment: @Eljay I know but just for test. I even tested and found that the compiler randomly choosed one of the class template definitions if they were defined through multi files because the templates are the weak symbols. But I wonder if we define a template in `first.cpp` file and explicitly instanciate one instanciation right in that file, then in `another.cpp` we also define the template but just declare the instanciation with `extern`, so the template defintion used should be from `first.cpp` where we have explicitly instanciated. Is it right?

Comment: ODR violation is IFNDR.

Comment: "I know I cannot expect anything specific but I expect something specific". Just don't.